# Cómo realizar una consulta LINQ, Lambda?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Quisiera saber como realizar una consulta `SQL en LAMBDA` o `linq` en `c#`, esta es la consulta:

```
select Agricultor.Nombre, Producto.Nombre, 
Producto.Precio from Agricultor, Producto
where Agricultor.IdAgricultor = Producto.IdProductor
```

Comment: Bueno parece que estas utilizando un JOIN, por lo que en este caso podria recomendar crear un vista en SQL donde ejecutes tu consulta cómo la tienes ahora, y del lado de C# solo la mandes llamar con el LINQ cómo una consulta simple.

Comment: Entiendo, lo que pasa es que quiero hacerlo solo con lambda, todo desde C# pero no sé como realizar la consulta.

Comment: ¿Una vista para un join? no hay que exagerar, es fácil revisa este link http://www.dotnetlearners.com/linq/linq-to-sql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: Es una consulta sencilla. Revisa la documentación de [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Esto es lo más cercano que pude realizar:

```
        var oo = Agricultor.Join(Producto, x => x.idAgricultor, y => y.idProducto, (agricultor, producto) => new
        {
            agricultor,
            producto
        })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.agricultor.idAgricultor,
            x.producto.idProducto
        }).ToList();
```

Básicamente primero ponemos el IEnumerable que es es el principal, luego hacemos join con otro IEnumerable, despues especificamos la clave de relación del primero, despues la del segundo, establecemos el resultado y al final sólo establecemos que vamos a seleccionar.

Answer (score 0):

en query de linq

```
var oo = from agri in Agricultor
         join pro in Producto on agri.IdAgricultor equals pro.IdProductor
         select new {agri,pro};
```

Comment: es mas legible que las lambdas y si quieres eriqueser al final puedes usar lambdas con expresiones de extensiones de metodos o sea puedes unir linq de query con lambdas pero al revez no

Comment: No agreges comentarios a tu propia respuesta, cuando lo que en realidad queres es poner mas informacion. Editala usando el boton [edit]. Tene en cuenta que esta respuesta la reporto el sistema como de baja calidad, ya que es solo codigo sin ninguna explicacion (tal vez, porque la explicacion esta en el comentario y no en la respuesta). Mira por favor [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esta lambda

```
var resultLambda = _objConexion.Agricultor.join( _objConexion.Producto, a => a.IdAgricultor, p.IdProductor, (a, p) => new { Agricultor = a, Producto = p}).Where( aandp => aandp.agricultor.IdAgricultor  == aandp.Producto ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Si la consulta te devuelve una lista solo debes hacer esto

```
  var resultLambda = _objConexion.Agricultor.join( _objConexion.Producto, a => a.IdAgricultor, p.IdProductor, (a, p) => new { Agricultor = a, Producto = p}).Where( aandp => aandp.agricultor.IdAgricultor  == aandp.Producto ).ToList();
```

o utilizar la consulta LINQ

```
var resultLinq = from a in Agricultor
                 join p in Producto
                 where a.IdAgricultor equals p.IdProductor
                 select new ResultadoDto() {
                         NombreAgri = a.Nombre,
                         NombrePro = p.Nombre,
                         Precio = p.Precio
                  };
```

Si la consulta te devuelve una lista solo debes hacer esto

```
var resultLinq = (from a in Agricultor
                 join p in Producto
                 where a.IdAgricultor equals p.IdProductor
                 select new ResultadoDto() {
                         NombreAgri = a.Nombre,
                         NombrePro = p.Nombre,
                         Precio = p.Precio
                  }).ToList();
```

El Dto lo creas de esta forma

```
 public class ResultadoDto
    {
        private string NombreAgri;
        private string NombrePro;
        private float Precio;
}
```